# Finding a tricky quotient set

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

We will denote by $\mathbb{K}$ one of the fields $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. On $\mathbb{K}\times \mathbb{K}$ we define the following equivalence relation:
$$(a,b)\equiv (a', b') \iff \exists (q,\alpha)\in \mathbb{K}^{*}\times \mathbb{K} \text{ such that } \begin{cases} a=q^2a'+\alpha^2-b\alpha \\ b=qb'+2\alpha \end{cases}.$$
We wish to determine the quotient set $\mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{K}/\equiv$ $\space$ for all $\mathbb{K}$s.
This problem was an extra problem in my abstract algebra class (don't worry, this isn't an attempt to cheat, I am posting this a week after the solution was due to be sent) and I kind of got stuck when it comes to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$.
For $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, the things were nice and easy, because the original question asked me to prove that $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}/\equiv$ is equal to $\{\hat{(0,0)}, \hat{(0,1)}\}$ and this can be checked through (tedious) direct computations.
For $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, a friend came up with the idea of expressing $\alpha$ from the second equation and then substituing it in the first one. This gives us the following equivalent characterisation of the equivalence relation:
$$(a,b)\equiv (a', b') \iff \exists q\in \mathbb{K}^{*} \text{ such that } 4a+b^2=q^2(4a'+b'^2) \space (*).$$
(notice that this works for all $\mathbb{K}$s, the case $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ can be solved much easier by using this, but I didn't really need to think that much for that one since direct computations worked in my context)
For real numbers, this rewrites as $(a,b)\equiv (a', b') \iff \operatorname{sgn}(4a+b^2)=\operatorname{sgn}(4a'+b'^2)$.
As a result, there will be three equivalence classes: the parabola $4x+y^2=0$, its interior and its exterior. A representative for each of these are, respectively, $(0,0), (-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, so $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}/\equiv \space = \{\hat{(0,0)}, \hat{(-1,0)}, \hat{(0,1)}\}$.
For $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$, the things get pretty nasty by this approach. In this case, $(*)$ rewrites as $(a,b)\equiv (a',b') \iff \sqrt{\frac{4a+b^2}{4a'+b'^2}}\in \mathbb{Q}$ and I haven't been able to make any further progress.

Comment: I belive there is a typo in (*). The RHS of the equivalence must be $\exists q\in \mathbb{K}^*$ such that $4a+b^2=q^2(4a'+b'^2)$. Similarly in the last characterization over the rationals it must be $4a'+b'^2$ in the denominator inside the square root.

Comment: @Albert thank you, it most certainly was a typo!

Comment: You can look at the map $K\times K\rightarrow K,(a,b)\mapsto 4a+b^2$ and post-compose the projection map $K\rightarrow K/(K^{\times})^2$. Your equivalence relation is precisely having equal images under this composition, so the isomorphism theorem for sets tells us this corresponds bijectively to the image of the composition and the maps are clearly surjective. So what you seek is to describe $K/(K^{\times})^2$. If you remove the equivalence class of $0$, this becomes $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^2$, which is an object studied in field theory.

Comment: @Thorgott I tried to use the universal property of the quotient set (I think that this is what you mean by "the isomorphism theorem for sets", if it is a distinct theorem that I haven't heard of please let me know), but to no avail. Could you please develop this further into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\varphi\colon K\times K\rightarrow K,\,(a,b)\mapsto4a+b^2$. This map is surjective, since $\varphi(a/4,0)=a$ for all $a\in K$. Next, consider the projection map $\pi\colon K\rightarrow K/(K^{\times})^2$, where $K/(K^{\times})^2$ is the set of equivalence classes under the equivalence relation $a\sim b:\Leftrightarrow\exists q\in K^{\times}\colon a=q^2b$ for $a,b\in K$. This map is surjective by definition. Your equation $(\ast)$ now says that
$$(a,b)\sim(a^{\prime},b^{\prime})\Leftrightarrow(\pi\circ\varphi)(a,b)=(\pi\circ\varphi)(a^{\prime},b^{\prime}),\qquad\forall (a,b),(a^{\prime},b^{\prime})\in K\times K.$$
Now, the universal property of the quotient set tells us that $\pi\circ\varphi\colon K\times K\rightarrow K/(K^{\times})^2$ factors as a bijection $\widetilde{\pi\circ\varphi}\colon K\times K/\sim\rightarrow K/(K^{\times})^2$, sending the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ in $K\times K$ to the equivalence class of $4a+b^2$ in $K/(K^{\times})^2$. (This holds true for any field $K$ of characteristic $\neq2$.)

In the specific case $K=\mathbb{Q}$, there is also a somewhat natural system of representatives of $K/(K^{\times})^2$. The equivalence class $[0]=\{0\}$ is represented by $0$ and every other equivalence class contains a unique square-free integer.